# Angular table - resizing large tables with poor performance

Tags: javascript, css, angular, draggable

In my Angular 6 app I have a table that is dynamically generated from a JSON file and it has an option to resize each column. It works fine when there are 20-30 rows, but it can also be a lot more and then performance issues are starting to appear. You can see below what i have tried:

This is a main part of the component where resize method is used:

```
<th class="dsx-table__head-cell" #t3SdiCell>
        T3 SDI Comment
        <span
                class="icon-cancel dsx-table__reset-size"
                (click)="resetColumnSize($event)">
        </span>
        <span draggable="true"
              class="dsx-table__resizer"
              (dragstart)="resizeTableCellStart($event)"
              (dragend)="resizeTableCellFinish($event)"
              (drag)="resizeTableCell($event)">
        </span>
    </th>
```

Basically you drag a span that is always on the right and it changes the width of a TH, which also changes all of the TDs.

Here is a TS file:

```
import {AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DsxItem, DsxSourceItem, ProjectDataStoreService} from '../../../../../service/store/project-data-store.service';
import {DsxScrollerService, generateDsxPreviewIdFromDsxItem} from '../../../../../service/source/dsx-scroller.service';
import {LocalStorageService} from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dsx-table',
templateUrl: './dsx-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dsx-table.component.scss'],
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DsxTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@Input() public source = null;

@ViewChild('mainTable')
mainTable: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('speakerCell')
speakerCell: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('tcInCell')
tcInCell: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('typeCell')
typeCell: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('dialogCell')
dialogCell: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('t3ApproverCell')
t3ApproverCell: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('t3SdiCell')
t3SdiCell: ElementRef;

private offset = null;
private mousePosition = null;
private ghostImage = null;
private mainTableWidth = null;

constructor(private projectDataStore: ProjectDataStoreService,
            private dsxScroller: DsxScrollerService,
            private localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ghostImage = new Image();
    this.ghostImage.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';
    this.ghostImage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    this.mainTableWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.mainTable.nativeElement).width, 10);
    this.loadFromLocalStorage();
}

public resizeTableCellStart(event) {
    this.offset = event.target.offsetLeft - event.clientX;
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.ghostImage, 0, 0);
}

public resizeTableCellFinish(event) {
    this.mousePosition = event.clientX;
    const roundedPosition = Math.round((((this.mousePosition + this.offset) - 5) / this.mainTableWidth) * 100);
    if (this.mousePosition + this.offset > 5) {
        event.target.style.right = '0.3rem';
        event.target.parentNode.style.width = roundedPosition + '%';
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.ghostImage, 0, 0);
    } else {
        event.target.style.right = '0.3rem';
        event.target.parentNode.style.width = '0.5rem';
    }
    this.saveToLocalStorage();
}

public resizeTableCell(event) {
    this.mousePosition = event.clientX;
    if (this.mousePosition + this.offset > 5) {
        event.target.style.right = '0.3rem';
        event.target.parentNode.style.width = (this.mousePosition + this.offset) + 'px';
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.ghostImage, 0, 0);
    } else {
        event.target.style.right = '0.3rem';
        event.target.parentNode.style.width = '0.5rem';
    }
}

public saveToLocalStorage() {
    this.localStorage.set('speakerCell', this.speakerCell.nativeElement.style.width);
    this.localStorage.set('tcInCell', this.tcInCell.nativeElement.style.width);
    this.localStorage.set('typeCell', this.typeCell.nativeElement.style.width);
    this.localStorage.set('dialogCell', this.dialogCell.nativeElement.style.width);
    this.localStorage.set('t3ApproverCell', this.t3ApproverCell.nativeElement.style.width);
    this.localStorage.set('t3SdiCell', this.t3SdiCell.nativeElement.style.width);
}

public loadFromLocalStorage() {
    this.speakerCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('speakerCell');
    this.tcInCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('tcInCell');
    this.typeCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('typeCell');
    this.dialogCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('dialogCell');
    this.t3ApproverCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('t3ApproverCell');
    this.t3SdiCell.nativeElement.style.width = this.localStorage.get('t3SdiCell');
}

public resetColumnSize(event) {
    event.target.parentNode.style.width = null;
    this.saveToLocalStorage();
}
}
```

So my question is - can it be done a little better, so it performs smoother with larger tables? So far I've just disabled the resizeTableCell method so the change happens only after drag end, but it's not an ideal solution, because width change is still happening after 0.5-1s. I will appreciate all the ideas.